# Intellij: how to keep added content roots after gradle refresh?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Intellij: how to keep added content roots after gradle refresh?

For example,

```
Project structures ... > add content root
/path/foo
/path/bar
```

After making some changes to a project's build.gradle, refresh gradle projects. But all added content roots are gone. How to keep them?

Comment: IDEA uses Gradle build script as initial source of project configuration. So, your additional content root should be mentioned in build file.

Comment: how to add that in build.gradle? thanks.